# passing video url using json in ios

Tags: ios, json, video, nsurlconnection

hi I'm trying to view the videos from my server for that i have stored the video url in mysql database
using the json and php code I'm passing the url to the iOS but now I'm getting some problem here

previously using this same format fetching the images from my server but now i want to view the videos this is the first time im working on the videos not to able to get it

this is the code which i used to fetch the url form database and liking to the ios nsurl format

tabecell.m file code:

```
#import "vediopoliticalCell.h"
#import "vedios.h"
@implementation vediopoliticalCell
   //@synthesize movieplayer,titile;

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
          {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
               // Initialization code
                  }
                       return self;
             }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
          {
              [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

              // Configure the view for the selected state
           }

       -(void)setDataSource:(vedios *)inVideosObj
         {
              self.titile.text = inVideosObj.title;

             NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video];
             NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
             connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
             self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
         }
        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
         {
              [self.responseData appendData:data];
         }

           - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
             {
                 MPMoviePlayerController *play = [[MPMoviePlayerController    alloc]initWithContentURL:self.responseData];
             }
```

In this code:

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
             {
                 MPMoviePlayerController *play = [[MPMoviePlayerController    alloc]initWithContentURL:self.responseData];
             }
```

im getting a waring called:
**Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSMutableData *' to parameter of type Nsurl***

previously for the image i using this code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
   {
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.responseData];
       self.thumbImageView.image = image;
   }
```

now i dont know how to use for the videos please can anyone help me with this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.responseData is NSMutableData but MPMoviePlayerController needs url to load the video.

So, first you have to get url-string from data.

```
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]]
MPMoviePlayerController *play = [[MPMoviePlayerController    alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL urlWithString:url]];
//Now present the MPMoviePlayerController
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In `setDataSource:` method

```
-(void)setDataSource:(vedios *)inVideosObj
{
     self.titile.text = inVideosObj.title;

     NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video];
     MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoDeatilView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
     //now you can present this videoDeatilView and 
     //[videoDeatilView.moviePlayer play]; will play the video
}
```

Comment: your code blocks the main thread.It's wont give aesthetic UX.Thats the reason why he used NSURLCOnnection in first place.

Comment: no, just pass the url to MPMoviePlayerViewController, it will take care of the rest and stream the video in the background - no need to download the video itself before